# Writing to Delta Tables from Azure Function App

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, delta-lake

I am implementing a 3-hop data pipeline holding every layer of data as delta tables in azure storage accounts. Currently I ingest data as json using either data factory or function apps, and do all processing in databricks.

My question is this: Is there any .Net package that enables writing the ingested json files from an Azure Function App directly to a Storage Account delta table?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?  Would you have a link to demonstrate how to read a SDLS Delta table using a Function App in either C# or Python?

Answer (score 2):

The NuGet package is this one: [Microsoft.Spark.Extensions.Delta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Spark.Extensions.Delta/)

The problem with it is that it's just a thin wrapper around [this Java class](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/java/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable.html), and communicates with it [via an IPC socket](https://github.com/dotnet/spark/blob/main/src/csharp/Microsoft.Spark/Interop/Ipc/JvmBridge.cs). In other words, it only works on a machine with spark engine installed.

Installing all the dependency tree (spark, java, etc.) onto a .NET-based Azure Functions instance is theoretically possible, but isn't worth the effort. Much easier would be to write that Azure Function in another language. E.g. [here is a python example](https://github.com/scale-tone/azure-function-pump-data-to-delta-lake), it pumps JSON-formatted events from an Azure Service Bus queue into a Delta Lake table. Can be adjusted accordingly to take data from anywhere else.